# Angular Replace ng-model sth else

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I transform own tag to template

```
<div><input .../><strong>text</strong></div>
```

I need have same values in both inputs.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wYk6N5XXH2RPtPAwsxmd?p=preview)

if i fixed scope from scope: {value:'@'}, to scope: false, it works,

but

I can't touch scope {value:'@'}

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. You can't touch `{value:'@'}` but you can touch the directive's link function ? Or what can you touch ? And why does the template have 2 ng-model attrobutes on the same element ?

Comment: 2 ng-model is my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on with your code is `scope: {...}` sets up a new scope, so those 2 directive scopes have no communication with each other. I would probably use a `scope: false` for this example, so that the directives would share the same scope. Why is it that you "can't touch `scope {value:'@'}`"?

What you can do is set up your app with a controller which would supply a parent scope. Then prototypically refer to the parent's scope value from each directive scope.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gTdfKKGR0krm7wgtYuFP?p=preview

More reading: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes (note the video within that reading title "always have a '.' in your ng-models")

Comment: Thanks. It works. Why? Just if scope != false -> increment doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure your exact use-case beyond this example, but here's an example of using Angular's native `$index` variable: http://plnkr.co/edit/qGRj2ULpftiTKr9k76dr?p=preview

Comment: Yes. It's good example. But I have unknown count of own tags)